# Multiple Pnotify notifications with various sizes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pnotify

I'm trying to display 2 notifications one after another with `Pnotify`, but I'm having an issue: The second notification always get the same height as the first. So, if the second notification is bigger than the first one, it doesn't fit in the notification container:
[image: Notifications with wrong sizes]

Here's a fiddle with some test (I'm not sure if you would be able to run it cause of external resources) : https://jsfiddle.net/Alarid/y8b8pdcj/1/

Code :

```
new PNotify({
    title: 'Information',
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    type: 'warning',
    nonblock: {
        nonblock: true,
        nonblock_opacity: .2
    },
    styling: "bootstrap3",
    delay: 3000,
    addclass: "stack-bottomright",
});

new PNotify({
    title: 'Information',
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed erat eget odio auctor rutrum. Morbi non est eu risus pharetra varius. Morbi lorem neque",
    type: 'success',
    nonblock: {
        nonblock: true,
        nonblock_opacity: .2
    },
    styling: "bootstrap3",
    delay: 3000,
    addclass: "stack-bottomright",
});
```

Comment: you can add external resources to your fiddle by using  the Resources panel on the left.

Comment: That's what I've done. But when I share the link, they are not available anymore, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: You have a console error: *ReferenceError: PNotify is not defined.*

Comment: can you add your css to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gv0wt2x0/3/ and update it

Comment: I know, but I don't know why, I've put the JS Link in external resources...

Comment: I don't use any particular CSS to do this, notifications are styled with Bootstrap.

Comment: I just discovered that the problem comes from the "stack-bottomright" class... But I need to put my notifications at this place, so i'm quite stuck at this point.